# Compartir enlaces de secciones que están dentro de la app

Tags: reactjs, web

Cree un pagina web con react  y esta alojada aqui https://geocartos.000webhostapp.com/ .

Ahora si quiero compartir un enlace de una sección de la página por ejemplo Doctores https://geocartos.000webhostapp.com/doctores

Cuando lo abro sale error 404.

¿Cómo puedo compartir link de secciones sin que salga 404 , es posible ?

Comment: No sé como solucionar el error pero si sé su causa. Resulta que tu tienes una SPA, cuando entras directamente al sitio https://geocartos.000webhostapp.com/ carga la pagina y si tu presionas algún link ya no funciona como una página común (yendo al servidor a buscar esa URL), si no que es el cliente el que te genera esa nueva página y te coloca una URL en el navegador que es "falsa" (por llamarle de alguna manera). Entonces si tu vas ahora directamente al servidor por esta URL https://geocartos.000webhostapp.com/doctores el servidor no tiene idea de esa ruta, porque el servidor no conoce

Comment: lo que tu tienes en React, para él no existe esa ruta, ahora fíjate que si entras a https://geocartos.000webhostapp.com/index.html te da el error 404 pero con el formato que tu tienes en React, el anterior 404 te lo arrojaba el server. Como te decia, no se la solución, supongo que en el servidor tienes que redireccionar todas las peticiones a la raíz, seguramente en el `.htaccess`

Comment: para poder navegar entre rutas sin obtener un 404 por parte del navegador en el caso de las Single Page Aplication, lo que puedes hacer es manejar las rutas con hash # asi de esta forma te va a funcionar
https://geocartos.000webhostapp.com/#/doctores
asi cuando hagas las redirecciones antepone el hash #
aqui te dejo la documentación de React Router https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/hash-router

Comment: No concuerdo con tu punto, en mi respuesta indico que use un hash en su ruta para que asi no obtenga el 404, que es justo lo que busca la persona